# linear system of first-order differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$mx′′(t) = −kx(t) − cx′(t)$

Express the equation of motion as a linear system of first-order differential equations.

I was wondering if this is the right way of thinking of it..

1. $cx'(t) = -kx(t) - mx''(t)$
2. integral of $kx(t) = -cx'(t) - mx''(t)$
3. derivative of $mx''(t) = -kx(t) - cx'(t)$

If so, how would I solve $2/3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use $x''(t) = (x'(t))'$. So instead of having **one** equation of second order, you introduce a new function, say $y(t) = x'(t)$, and you have **two** equations of first order:

$$
x'(t) = y(t)\\
y′(t) = −\frac{k}{m} x(t) − \frac{c}{m}y(t)
$$

This can be written in matrix form and solved by standard methods, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation).

Answer (score 0):

To change equations to first order we use substitution.

$\phi_1(t)=x(t)$

$\phi_2(t)=x'(t)$

Then:

$\phi_1'(t)=x'(t)=\phi_2(t)$

$\phi_2'(t)=x''(t)=\dfrac{-k\phi_1(t)-c\phi_2(t)}{m}$

Now you have a system of two first-order differential equations.